# reflection.js with images in a .net updatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, reflection, updatepanel

I have an update panel which contains various placeholders with images.

These images have a reflection added using [reflection.js](http://cow.neondragon.net/stuff/reflection/).

The trouble is, when the update panel runs, the reflection script does not always run. There's no real pattern to when it does not work and on which panels it does not work with.

Here's a sample of my code so you can see how it's working (I've cut it down to 2 panels for this example to keep the code short)... The most baffling thing is why is works some times and not others.

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src="/scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="reflection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form runat="server" id="loginform">
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="Lnk1" OnClick="fnc1" runat="server" Text="Read more..." />
    </li>
    <li>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="Lnk2" OnClick="fnc2" runat="server" Text="Read more..." />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Lnk1" EventName="Click" />
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Lnk2" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PH1"> <img src="myimage1.jpg" title="myimage1" width="200" height="133" class="zoomImage reflect rheight36 ropacity25" /> </asp:PlaceHolder>
      <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PH2"> <img src="myimage2.jpg" title="myimage2" width="200" height="93" class="zoomImage reflect rheight51 ropacity25" /> </asp:PlaceHolder>
    </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
</body>
```

And here's the vb code...

```
Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal E As EventArgs)
        PH1.Visible = False
        PH2.Visible = False
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
               PH1.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub

Sub fnc1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    PH1.Visible = True
End Sub

Sub fnc2(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    PH2.Visible = True
End Sub
```

I've slightly adapted the reflection.js file to make it work at all in the updatepanel as follows...

```
function load() {
    addReflections();
    // Line below added for updatepanel...
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(addReflections);
}

window.onload = function () { load(); }
```

Comment: In your actual code are you specifying UpdateMode="Conditional"?  If not your panels are updating more often than on your triggered events...

Comment: I hadn't done that, however it didn't help. Thanks though!

Comment: Too bad - was hoping for a quick win.  Maybe you should try adding a debugging trap above add_endRequest to make sure things are getting re-added when you expect.  Just make `debugger;` the first line of code in load() and run in IE with debugging enabled...

Comment: OK... a little bit of progress... It seems to work fine in IE, but not in Safari, Chrome or Firefox on PC or Mac.

Comment: All the code?  Or just that debugger line?  The debugger line is, unfortunately, IE proprietary.  At least it would give you the capability to confirm in one browser though that the events you expect to fire are firing...

Comment: Had to remove the debugger line for the other browsers...

Comment: @Brian let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2536/discussion-between-tom-and-brian)